# Modelling Peters Swing from the Becoming Spider-Man Scene - The Amazing Spider-Man (2012)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, projectile-motion, circular-motion

I am currently working on a project where I model the physics and calculus involved in a successful swing done by spiderman. I have broken down his swing into three segments. The first segment models his initial jump off building one which is 225m in height, until he reaches a point 100m from the ground where he connects to building two via his web. I've calculated his velocity when he is 100m from the ground, including air resistance and assuming he falls straight down, his velocity is 38.1m/s. The issue I am having is how to connect segment 1 and segment 2 together. Segment 2 is his pendulated swing that concludes when he gains enough speed and reaches a certain point of release that will project him to a maximum landing point on building 3. I have an differential equation that will model the motion of a pendulum including air resistance, but my problem is how I will incorporate that initial velocity into the equation and how it effects angular velocity. My second problem is that, is the motion of a pendulum the right way to approach the question? As I will need to determine the correct point of release at a certain time and angle that will allow for maximum projection. Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will probably get more realistic and survivable results if you model the pendulum as elastic, a spring with a high spring constant and damping. Otherwise the body is the spring that has to accommodate the change in velocity and acceleration.